# JS enable & disable microphone

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm trying to enable and disable my microphone on press but I can't really get it to work, I'm new to javascript.

Thank you for help.. PS Im using webrtc

```
navigator.getUserMedia({"audio":USE_AUDIO},
                function(stream) { /* user accepted access to a/v */
                    console.log("Access granted to audio/video");
                    local_media_stream = stream;
                    var local_media = $("<audio>");
                    local_media.attr("autoplay", "autoplay");
                    local_media.attr("muted", "true"); /* always mute ourselves by default */
                    local_media.attr("controls", "");
                    $('body').append(local_media);
                    attachMediaStream(local_media[0], stream);

                    if (callback) callback();

                    $('.testHold').mousedown(function() {
                      $('.tracker').html("holding holding holding");
                          local_media.attr("muted", "false");

                    }).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
                      $('.tracker').text('Left the button');
                        local_media.attr("muted", "true");

                    });

                }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  $('.testHold').mousedown(function() {
                      $('.tracker').html("holding holding holding");
                      stream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = true;

                    }).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
                      $('.tracker').text('Left the button');
                        stream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false;

                    });
```